# jpa2 CriteriaBuilder order by "ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list"

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-order-by, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

I'm writing a query with **CriteriaBuilder**, but it has not been possible to add the **order by** clause, because an error it's thrown with the message *ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list* this are my entities.

```
public class A{
  Integer aId;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "bId", nullable = false)
  B       classB;
  //setter and getter.
}

public class B{
    Integer bId;
    String name;
    //setter and getter.

}
```

my query look like this.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = super.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
        Root<A> aRoot = cq.from(A.class);
        Join<A, B> joinB = aRoot.join("b", JoinType.INNER);

        cq.distinct( true );

        cq.orderBy( cb.asc( joinB.get("name") ));

        return super.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

This is the sql tha hibernate generates.

```
select
    distinct a0_.aId as aId,
    a0_.bId as bId,
from
    a a0_ 
inner join
    b b2_ 
        on a0_.aId=b2_.bId 
order by
    b2_.name asc //this is where the error comes
```

As you can see. **B** it is not in the **select** clause. so, how do i add **B**?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html) is an example how it should works.

Comment: Thank you for your help, at the end the solution was to add a group by and delete the distinct.

Comment: Thank you the Question and the comment. Although I think the above comment should also be posted as answer to the question. It seems to be still valid today.