# Implementing NULLS LAST with JPA CriteriaBuilder API

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Spring/Hibernate/MySQL/JPA here. I have the following code:

```
public void setOrdering(
    SearchRequest searchRequest,
    CriteriaQuery query,
    CriteriaBuilder builder,
    Root<? extends MyEntity> root) {

  String sortParam = "reportedOn";

  Expression expression = builder.selectCase()
    .when(builder.isNull(root.get(sortParam)), root.get(sortParam))
    .otherwise(root.get(sortParam));

  Order order = (searchRequest.isAscending())
    ? builder.asc(expression)
    : builder.desc(expression);

  query.orderBy(order);

}
```

Basically, I'm trying to implement the `CriteriaBuilder`/JPA equivalent of:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  <lots of predicates here>
ORDER BY reported_on IS NULL, reported_on <ASC/DESC>
```

I already have the WHERE predicates added, I'm just struggling with the `query.orderBy(...)`.

At runtime, when `searchRequest.isAscending()` is false, the results come back working just fine, with the records that contain a `null` `reported_on` value ordered at the end of the results.

But if `searchRequest.isAscending()` is true, the `NULLS LAST` attempt does not appear to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like JPA's `CriteriaBuilder` supports `NULLS LAST`. I actually got this working using a SQL "hack":

```
String sortParam = "reportedOn";

Order order = (searchRequest.isAscending())
  ? builder.desc(builder.neg(root.get(sortParam)))
  : builder.desc(root.get(sortParam));

query.orderBy(order);
```

Basically `ORDER BY -reported_on DESC` does the same thing as `ORDER BY reported_on ASC` but it sorts records with `NULL` `reported_on` values all the way to the bottom of the search results, which is what `NULLS LAST` is supposed to do.

Comment: if you want to define the nulls order for all the queries and not just one query at a time you should override public `String renderOrderByElement(String expression, String collation, String order, NullPrecedence defaultNullPrecedence)` in your dbms dialect and based on the values of order and defaultNullPrecedence and based on what you want you could invoke super with either NullPrecedence.LAST or NullPrecedence.FIRST or NullPrecedence.NONE

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the Spring and JPA APIs, here `query` is from the JPA API so you need to sort using something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
Root root = ...
query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("reportedOn")));
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume (+1) but how would I add a `NULLS LAST` clause in there to force records with `null` reportedOn values to always show up at the end of the results, regardless of the ASC/DESC specification?

Comment: For instance, the I'm trying to make the `CriteriaBuilder` equivalent of: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <lots of predicates here> ORDER BY reported_on IS NULL, reported_on <ASC/DESC>`. I already have the `WHERE` predicates added, I'm just struggling with the `query.orderBy(...)`.

Comment: Instead of using a simple path in the asc(...) call you'll need to pass an expression, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520991/jpa-criteria-api-order-by-null-last/41521006

Comment: Thanks again @Guillaume (+1 again). Please see my latest edits. I am now passing in an expression but it only seems to work when I use `builder.desc(...)`, not `builder.asc(...)`. Anything look "off" to you?